# Foreign key to multiple tables in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Let's say that I have three tables in my DB:
Table A: ID, other fields
Table B: ID, other fields
Table C: FK, Type, other fields

The FK field of table C has to be a reference to the ID fields in tables A and B. The Type field determines which table the row refers to.
So, for example, if Type equals 'A' than FK refers to the id in Table A, and if Type equals 'B' then FK refers to the id in Table B.

How can I describe this relation in Entity Framework 6 assuming that changing the table structure is not an option?

Comment: Look for _polymorphic associations_.

Comment: You can always do a join query.